# How to get xgbregressor feature importance by column name?

Tags: feature-selection, xgboost, feature-engineering

```py
xgb = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.08, gamma=0,
  subsample=0.75, colsample_bytree=1, max_depth=7)

xgb.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')
xgb.feature_importances_
```

This will return the feature importance of the xgb with weight, but how to return it with column name?

Answer (score 4):

If you have `X_train` Dataframe then you can take columns from there and loop it with `feature_importances_`

```
for col,score in zip(X_train.columns,model.feature_importances_):
    print(col,score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

features = xgb.get_booster().feature_names
importances = xgb.feature_importances_
model.feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(features, importances), columns=['feature', 'importance']).set_index('feature')
```